# How can I call a .NET Web API method that returns a Task using Postman and avoid an error 404 not found?

Tags: .net, webapi

I've method on .net Web API.couldn't call this from postman.giving an error 404 not found.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class JobController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpPost]
 public Task<Job<string>> Create(Job<string> job)
 {
 }
}
```

try with
[HttpPost]
http://localhost:5000/job/Create
[HttpPost]
http://localhost:5000/job

but didn't work.

but when i changed Httppost attribute on method as "[HttpPost("Create")]" it's working.
but at the moment couldn't changed this...I've to keep it as it is.
need help on how to call this using postman.

** no issue with body parameters, hence it's perfectly fill to the object when i change Httppost attribute on method as "[HttpPost("Create")]".